# How to properly seperate PHP from HTML (Business logic from View)

Tags: php, html

I am learning to write better code and to not mix PHP code with HTML/CSS since that will be better both for me and people who will read my code after me. However I stumbled upon a situation where I have users with different roles and each role has it's own color/class/style/html. I end up putting either HTML code in my PHP logic or vice versa. Is there a nice way around this?

**PHP:**

```
if ($user_role == 'administrator') {
    $user_color == '#ff0000'; <-- CSS Style in my PHP
    $user_class == 'admin-class'; <-- CSS Class in my PHP
}

$users = [
    'username' => 'John',
    'user_color' => '#ff0000' <-- CSS Style in my PHP
]
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="<?= $user_class ?> style="color: <? $user_color ?>">Administrator</a>
```

or if I did not want HTML or CSS in my PHP then I end up putting PHP in my HTML.

**HTML**

```
foreach($users as $user):
    // Too much PHP logic in my HTML view
    if ($user->role == 'administrator') {
        $user_color = 'red';
    } else if ($user->role == moderator) {
        $user_color = '#00ff00'
    }

    <a style="color: <?= $user_color ?>">$user->username</a>
endforeach;
```

So either way, I end up mixing the two together. This is just one example where I need to adjust the HTML depending on some logic or conditions.

Comment: Just set `$user_role` as the class in your html, then have css classes in your css class for each role? `$user_color` seems unnecessary to me. If your only condition is "no PHP in a template" you can always use the likes of twig.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting a little PHP into "templating" files (e.g. `<a href="<?= $user_class; ?>" ... />`) when it concerns **display** logic - that's pretty much what the `.phtml` file extension is supposed to represent. Though you could use a templating engine; Symfony uses Twig for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a template engine (eg. [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/))

This will also secure your app from XSS etc. by default escaping your variables.

This way you can seperate your PHP and HTML like this:

**PHP**

```
$template = $twig->load('index.html');
echo $template->render(array(
  'user_color' => $user_color,
  'user' => $user
));
```

**HTML**

```
<a style="color: {{ $user_color }}">{{$user->username}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few options for that:

1. Add only classes to HTML using PHP, not CSS itself. Then use some CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for variables and additional functionality:

```
<a class="<?= $userRole; "></a>
```

In LESS:

```
@colorRed = #f00;

.administrator {
    color: @colorRed;
}
```

2. You can output CSS from PHP parser:

```
<link href="styles.php">
```

and there

```
.administrator {
    color: <?= $colorRed; ?>
}
```

3. Use [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) or other template engine

---

Since you are starting to learn structure, then consider using [MVC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Modern_web_app_architecture/MVC_architecture) principle: PHP code (a.k.a. `controller`) does not have to be responsible for representation (a.k.a. `view`). All UI stuff must be in Front-end side, not Back-end